# Minimum definition of a component Angular 4

Tags: angular

What is the minimum definition of a component, After looking at https://angular.io/api/core/Component it seems all are optional. 
Can some one explain what is the minimum definition.

Comment: Is it just selector and template/templateUrl ?

Comment: ... a Component is a special kind of directive that uses a simpler configuration which is suitable for a component-based application structure. ... {Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component} Hope it helps

Comment: He is asking the minimal attributes for configuration, not the definition as he puts it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The absolute minimal configuration for a `@Component` in angular is a template.
Both template properties are set to optional because you have to define either `template` or `templateUrl`.

When you don't define them, you will get an exception like this;

> No template specified for component 'ComponentName'

A `selector` property is not required, as you can also use your components in a route.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum configuration for Component is a **template**,

1. constructor is not required, it is auto generated
2. selector is also optional , component can be accessed via router by class name
3. template is required (either template or templateUrl)

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
     templateUrl: './minimum.component.html' // or
     template: '' 
   })
   export class MinimumComponent {}
   ```